# What is the cause and how to fix 503 errors with this in Apache error_log: "Broken pipe: ajp_ilink_send(): send failed"

Tags: jboss, cxf, ajp

I'm having intermittent problems with a servlet running on JBoss, with Apache forwarding it all requests via mod_proxy_ajp.so.

Sometimes, for REST requests, I get 503 errors from Apache. When this happens, the Apache error_log has this in it:

```
[Mon Oct 12 09:10:19 2009] [error] (32)Broken pipe: ajp_ilink_send(): send failed
[Mon Oct 12 09:10:19 2009] [error] (32)Broken pipe: proxy: send failed to 127.0.0.1:8009 (localhost)
```

After a few failed attempts, it starts working again.

I've googled some and found that I'm not the only one who has encountered the problem. The only solution I've found is to make sure that Apache is started after JBoss (I restart Apache after restarting JBoss).

The strange thing about this problem is that there are other servlets running in this JBoss and I don't have the problem there.

The servlet is CXF JAX-RS based.

Apache is 2.2.6.

Comment: `Broken pipe: send failed` messages generally mean that the connection was closed by the other side. Are there any exceptions in your JBoss logs at the same time? Maybe something is being logged at DEBUG or TRACE level that could provide a hint.

Comment: There are no exceptions in the JBoss logs at all, though I will turn on DEBUG levels to see if I can better understand what might be causing this.

Answer (score 1):

When using the AJP protocol, you have to be very careful to make sure that both sides of the communication (i.e. Apache and Tomcat) are configured with the same parameters. This is because AJP uses persistent, stateful connections, and both parties need to have the same expectations of the connection lifecycle.

I suggest giving the [relevant Tomcat docs a good read](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/timeouts.html). You'll probably have to modify either Apache's `mod_proxy_ajp` config, or Tomcat's AJP connector config, or both, so that they match. If the configs are even slightly different, AJP's performance can absolutely suck.

Comment: The first thing I did was to review the config and docs for mod_proxy_ajp. I also experimented to see if I could improve things by preventing the reuse of connections. No improvements.

Comment: Some more details on the steps you took to 'prevent the reuse of connections' might help.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same problem, but haven't found the cause either. An easy solution is to dump `mod_proxy_ajp` in favor of `mod_proxy_http`, if the slight performance penalty is acceptable. Works without problems at least for a website with max ~100 pageloads per second.

Comment: I'd like to fix the existing configuration.

Comment: Sure, but if that doesn't work, then there's at least an option :)

Comment: i just tried this, and it does work. 503's are now handled correctly, and are transparently passed to another node.... I also needed to add   "ProxyErrorOverride On" to my configuration, and as suggested, change my ajp:// links to http:// links as well.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that [this config generator](http://lbconfig.appspot.com/) is helpful when configuring AJP connections. Starting with the generated config and reading the relevant documentation was instructive.

(You can determine the "Apache mpm" parameter by executing `apachectl -l`, which lists compiled-in modules.)

Comment: That's a cool generator, but I don't have any load balancing. Just a straight connection.